# prepared statements dont work properly

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to use prepared statements when inserting values into db.

```
     $this->db = new Database();

    if(!empty($_POST['first_name'])){
        $this->first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['second_name'])){
        $this->second_name = $_POST['second_name'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['last_name'])){
        $this->last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['course'])){
        $this->course = $_POST['course'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['math'])){
        $this->math = $_POST['math'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['programming'])){
        $this->programming = $_POST['programming'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['english'])){
        $this->english = $_POST['english'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['history'])){
        $this->history = $_POST['history'];
    }
    try {
    $this->stmt = $this->db->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO students (first_name,second_name,last_name,course) VALUES (':first_name',':second_name',':last_name',':course')");
    $this->stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $first_name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $this->stmt->bindValue(':second_name', $second_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $this->stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $last_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $this->stmt->bindValue(':course', $course, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $this->stmt->execute();
    //$this->db->insertQuery("INSERT INTO objects (student_id,math,programming,english,history) VALUES ('','".$this->math."','".$this->programming."','".$this->english."','".$this->history."')");
    //$data = $this->db->stmt->fetchAll($q);
    //$this->view->render('index','template',$data);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

It doesnt work, the values in table are :first_name, :second_name, :third_name. What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php - follow the examples and you'll fix your code

Comment: you do not have to put quotes around the placeholders in prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepared statements work fine, it is your code that doesn't.

Change

```
$this->db->insertQuery("INSERT INTO students (id,first_name,second_name,last_name,course) VALUES ('',':first_name',':second_name',':last_name',':course')",array(':first_name'=>$this->first_name,':second_name'=>$this->second_name,':last_name'=>$this->last_name,':course'=>$this->course));
```

to

```
$this->db->insertQuery("INSERT INTO students (id,first_name,second_name,last_name,course) VALUES ('',':first_name',':second_name',':last_name',':course')",array('first_name'=>$this->first_name,'second_name'=>$this->second_name,'last_name'=>$this->last_name,'course'=>$this->course));
```

Notice the `:`'s are missing in the array of values to pass.

Comment: Are you [binding the parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) anywhere?

Comment: No i dont. There is an example $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);. Where should i get $name from?

Comment: I'm doing query in other file then insertQuery method is

Comment: Work through [this tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) it will answer most of your questions on PDO.

Comment: Remove the colons from bindValue()

Comment: Sorry, `:` is a colon.

Comment: like this? $this->stmt->bindValue('first_name', $first_name, PDO::PARAM_INT); ? still no result

Comment: there was a typo. I should write $this->first_name instead of $first_name. But even fixing it, it didnt worked out - $this->stmt->bindValue('first_name', $this->first_name);

Comment: i fixed it via tereskos answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove ":" from your array keys.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, I have removed id column from query

```
 $this->db->insertQuery("INSERT INTO students (first_name,second_name,last_name, course)      
 VALUES (':first_name',':second_name',':last_name',':course')",
 array('first_name'=>$this->first_name,'second_name'=>$this->second_name,
'last_name'=>$this->last_name,'course'=>$this->course));
```